# Instantcal API stopped working when switched to https

Tags: ssl, https, google-calendar-api

Basically we have sensitive information sitting in a private Google Calendar that we want to display to a client through a password protected, SSL secured website (No CMS). I do not want to share the calendar publicly.

Previously this worked with InstantCal without the SSL certificate using an ics iCal file. However, since moving to HTTPS we can no longer display the calendar.

Any suggestions to solve this will be greatly appreciated?